# Remove home directory from the URL with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

### Situation

I'll build my URL like follow:

1. The overview page on `/` (at `HomeController`).
2. The detail page on `/details/123` instead of `/home/details/123` knowing that 123 always is a number (at `HomeController`).
3. An info page on `/info` instead of `/home/info` (at `HomeController`).
4. The logon page on `/account/signin` (at `AccountController`).

I've don't have more pages on my application.

### Try 1

I've created two routes like follow:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The problem is that the account page gives a 404. The other pages works.

### Try 2

I've created one route like below:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

On each method inside the `HomeController` added a the `Route` attribute with the correct URL.

The problem is now that the overview and logon pages works the others gives now a 404.

### Question

How could I remove the home directory from the URL with ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use attribute routes you need to add

`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

to your RouteConfig.cs file.

It should go before your default route.